# multiple controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working on angular app which have lots of pages and i have make different controller for each page. All pages have only one same functionality that is calculator all other functionality is different.

```
Is it possible that i make calculator functionality in one controller and call it in all other controllers?
```

Comment: You can create a service, take a look at the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: You should craete a service with this functionality and add this as a DI in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement the functionality you want to share between controllers in a service or factory. This will also allow you to share data between controllers if needed.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services